# Why are Safari and Chrome's Javascript engine's running 1.5?

Tags: javascript

I was browsing the MDC Doc Center page on [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). And it mentions the introduction of the **let** keyword but only for use with browsers running at least the 1.7 release.

So I looked on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript_1.7#Versions) only to find that Safari and Chrome are on 1.5, while it seems every new release of Firefox has been using a newer release of JS.

Why is that?

Comment: Mozilla is basically doing its own thing.  The real next standard is ECMAScript 5, and currently really nobody's doing that (completely). (*edit* your chart gives IE9 and FF4 ES5 support, which may be true.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<script language="javascript1.7"></script>` for Chrome. Probably the same for Safari.

EDIT: It appears that while chrome does support at least some JS1.8 features, it does not support several 1.7 features, including `let`.

The most recent mention (9 days ago) on this from a V8 person is here:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/v8-users/-wu2BBL54pA/discussion

> Several features (let, modules, destructuring) seem interesting. What is V8's take on these features? And what is V8's general view on new features after EcmaScript5 ?

Was answered with:

> As we are doing with ES5, we will follow the language evolution when new specs are ratified in the EcmaScript spec committees and browser vendors agree to implement them. For some of the features we might start experimenting before the spec is ratified.

-Mads Sig Ager from the chromium project

Which is probably as close as we can get to "why."

Comment: Are you really sure that Chrome actually supports the 1.7 features?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Chrome supports array.reduce(), a JS1.8 feature, so I simply assumed that it had the 1.7 features covered, but upon testing it does seem that there is zero support for `let`. Sorry about that.

Comment: isn't the lang attribute depricated?